# Can i simplify this? (Xor of 1 bit in byte)

Tags: java, binary, set, bit

Is it possible to simplify this?

```
    public void setDisabled(boolean disabled) {
    if(disabled)
        this._rflags |= 1 << B1;
    else
        this._rflags &= ~(1 << B1);
}
```

It sets 1 bit of a byte (B1 = 2)

-edit-

Important info i missed

```
private char _rflags;

public static final char B1 = 1 << 2;
```

I wanted to keep it as a char and access single or multiple bits as different types because the data comes from C structs with unions. I will also be sending this data back over UDP.

Comment: Interesting question, but why would you want to simplify?  Are you trying to make is easier to understand, use less code, make it faster?

Comment: I mainly wanted it to look shorter as i have multiple uses of it, possible so i only have to change B1 in a single place

Comment: Put the bit setting/clearing code it in a macro, so it looks shorter and can be used for multiple situations

Comment: @bentech, if you want B1 to be a global variable, define it as such `public static final int B1 = 2;`  Then it can be referenced anywhere as `TheClasWhereYouDefinedIt.B1`.

Comment: public static final char B1 = 1 << 2;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real tidy way to make it shorter in Java. If you're going to repeat it, I'd say stick to the DRY principle and just put it in another method.

```
public void setDisabled(final boolean disabled) {
    toggleFlag(B1, disabled);
}

private void toggleFlag(final int bit, final boolean on) {
    if (on)
        this._rflags |= 1 << bit;
    else
        this._rflags &= ~(1 << bit);
}
```

Comment: I think a method would be best for my situation, although i will probably just leave it as before.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely to see some clever ways to restructure your method.  I'll provide a somewhat different answer.  It may or may not apply to your case; I don't have a lot of context.

One way would be to use a Factory to return an instance of a class.  If 'true' is passed into the Factory, a class containing this method is returned:

```
public void setDisabled() {
        _rflags &= ~(1 << B1);
}
```

If 'false' is passed in, the class returned by the factory would be a one-liner that performs the other calculation.  Note the lack of an argument; it isn't needed since the decision's already been made.  Squint regarding the access to `_rflags`; I dont' know what the classes look like.  Perhaps `_rflags` would be passed to this method.

In a more beautiful world, the entire class containing your `setDisabled(boolean)` method would be returned by the factory.  Then any cases of checking for the disabled flag could be abstracted away by the factory.

Answer (score 0):

Formal simplification : change *void* to *Object* (never used) in your signature :

```
 return disabled == true ? this._rflags |= 1 << B1 :  this._rflags &= ~(1 << B1);
```

Comment: Why not use *int* as return type if you want to abuse the choice operator in this way?

Comment: @Durandal *Object* is always a valid type, wathever the change made on *_rflags* type (a Long will be truncated) ; method remains OK and will be reused.

Comment: Very true. On the downside, it creates an unncessary garbage object with each invocation...

Comment: @Durandal if a number is certainly renturned, you can use a 'long'

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is converting the boolean to int. There is no way to express this without using some kind of conditional operator/if-else in java.

There are many ways to do this in a seemingly clever way, but IMHO its best to stick to a variant that is easily comprehended by most people (the if-else approach you already have).

You can write it a little more compact, but its still a mess:

```
final static int B1 = 2;

public void setDisabled(final boolean disabled) {
     final int bitmask = disabled ? (1 << B1) : 0;
     _rflags = (_rflags & ~bitmask) | bitmask; 
}
```

By the way, most people would probably find it more logical if the property would be named *enabled*, and the bit beeing set when the option is turned on (thats the way how setEnabled() semantically works for java.awt.Component etc.).

Comment: The naming isn't the best but i do have other methods such as setActive, setType, setRemote, setCount, setWild it all comes from a already implemented solution (C code structs)